# How to find out if an array contains class object or it is empty java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, jgrasp

When I call the fillArray method for the second time so that it finds the first empty space which I expect to be the second position in the array it replaces the first position too

```
 class Array {
   public static void main (String [] args) {

     Item[] A = new Item[10];
     fillArray(A);
     printArray(A);
     fillArray(A);
     printArray(A);
  }

  public static void fillArray(Item[] A) {
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Please enter item name");
     String word = keyboard.next();
     System.out.println("Please enter the price");
     double p = keyboard.nextDouble();
     System.out.println("Please enter quantity");
     int q = keyboard.nextInt();
     Item itema = new Item(word,q,p);
     for (int i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i] == null) {
           A[i]=itema;
           break;  
        }
     }
}

private static void printArray(Item[] A) {
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
        System.out.print(A[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

OUTPUT:

> Please enter item name
>   ball
>   Please enter the price
>   10
>   Please enter quantity
>   15
>   Item: ball  Quantity : 15 Price : 10.0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null
>   Please enter item name
>   bat
>   Please enter the price
>   18
>   Please enter quantity
>   19
>   Item: bat  Quantity : 19 Price : 18.0, Item: bat  Quantity : 19 Price : 18.0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null

Comment: @vinS. This question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Show printArray and the actual vs the expected output.

Comment: Show the code of `printArray` and also how you determined that the first element was overwritten. It doesn't look like it's overwritten, you may be misinterpreting things.

Comment: Also, please format your code with proper indentation.

Comment: @Hasnain Arif, can you format your code with proper indentation.

Comment: offcourse it will override, because you are calling `fillArray` two times.

Comment: Sorry for my indentation, this is my first ever post on stack overflow

Comment: Show us the code for the `Item` class. I suspect that you may have the name, price and quantity declared as static fields in this class.

Comment: @msandiford THANK YOU!! That was it, been stuck on this for the past 3 hours.

Comment: No problems.  Glad you got it sorted out!